# Add Property to Django Result Object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a property or two to a Django result object before I serialize it.  I'm fairly weak in my Python skills, so here we go.

I want to do:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
products.totalPages = 10
products.currentPage = 1
data = serializers.serialize('json', products)
```

Without trying to add the totalPages and currentPage properties, this code works fine.  But I'd like to add these properties so I can pass a nice looking JSON object back to the client.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `data = serializers.serialize('json', products)` returns a "list" ... so not sure where you want these extra attributes to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure where you would like those attrs to go onto that "list" that serialize returns.  Maybe you would like the data to be in a key in the final result:

```
import json

from django.core import serializers

products = Product.objects.all()
# data is a python list
data = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', products))
# d is a dict
d = {}
# data is a list nested in d
d['results'] = data
# more keys for d
d['totalPages'] = 10                                       
d['currentPage'] = 1
# data is a json string representation of the dict
data = json.dumps(d)
```

Maybe you can find use in aggregation and annotation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Update: note that the behavior of the default serializer might not be what you want. The code in `django.utils.simplejson.encoder` is highly optimized but I'm not quite sure how you would make it use custom properties and such. In the past, I have just made a method/property on my model class that converts the data in the instance to a dict containing exactly what I want. So, instead of

```
data = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', products))
```

you could use (provided you have defined a method, `as_dict` on Product):

```
data = [p.as_dict() for p in products]
```

Comment: This adds one item for all the products. What would you do if you had to display in your json object for every product a property called profit which would calculate the profit for each product entry, based on some logic?